# NSS: client certificate not found (nickname not specified)

Tags: paypal

Working with the Paypal API, yes i've checked my config files, yes i've checked username and password.... i'm outa ideas.  I'm using the ExpressCheckout API downloaded from  and everytime i try call the setExpressCheckout method i get the following error:

NSS: client certificate not found (nickname not specified)

I know it's something to do with an SSL error, how do i go about solving the problem?

Comment: I presume that this started happening to you a few days ago and before that it worked. Am I right ?

Comment: Yes that's correct. Is there any way of rectifying the problem?

Answer (score 3):

On August 3 and August 5 PayPal renewed the SSL certificates for the following API endpoints:

- api.paypal.com
- api-3t.paypal.com
- api-aa.paypal.com
- api-aa-3t.paypal.com

If you need to import the new PayPal SSL certificates into your application or system keystore/truststore you can download them from https://ppmts.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/920/. If you don't typically import the PayPal SSL certificates into your keystore/truststore, no action is required on your part.

For Sandbox please use this link: https://ppmts.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/924 to Download the new SSL Certificate.

Answer (score 2):

Check the paypal's server domain you send request to.
It should be api.paypal.com for certificate based authorization and api-3t.paypal.com for signature based authorization.

https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_nvp_NVPAPIOverview#id084E30V0RE9