# Paypal curl error: NSS: client certificate not found (nickname not specified)

Tags: php, ssl, curl, paypal

I'm trying to curl to PayPal to create payment URL, and I've bought a cert meet PayPal requirement.

When I first call the curl it return  error

`NSS: client certificate not found (nickname not specified)`

But when I try to reload the page within few second the curl return success.

Is there any way for me to set the cert in curl?

> I've read the other [ansewer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12412825/nss-client-certificate-not-found-nickname-not-specified) but some links were dead and the answer does not work for me.

```
 <?php
 $curl = curl_init();

 curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
   CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment",
   CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
   CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
   CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
   CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
   CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
   CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
   CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => '{"intent":"sale","redirect_urls":{"return_url":"'.$return.'","cancel_url":"'.$cancel.'"},"payer":{"payment_method":"paypal"},"transactions":[{"amount":{"total":"'.$amount.'","currency":"HKD"}}]}',
   CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
     "authorization: Bearer $token",
     "cache-control: no-cache",
     "content-type: application/json",
     "postman-token: 7ca12352-aa45-2c4e-d87d-fdd09795121d"
   ),
 ));

 $response = curl_exec($curl);
 $err = curl_error($curl);

 curl_close($curl);

 // If I added this refresh code it works!?
 /*
 if ($err) {
     header("Refresh:0");
 }
 */
```